# How to calculate Price and Quantity for dynamically inputs using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm building Ordering food web application using PHP, Js, and MySQL and couldn't calculate price and quantity for the dynamically inputs.

I can calculate only the price but without quantity I have no idea how to implemented with coding, so please if anyone know the solution I will really appreciated.

Finally this picture will explain my theory to can getting my point well:
[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkpwA.jpg)

And here is my HTML code:

```
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4"></label>
                      <div id ="diva" class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="box">
                          <header>
                            <h5>تفاصيل الطلب</h5>
                            </header>
                            <div class="body getval">
                              <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="control-label col-lg-2">الصنف</label>
                                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                                      <select id="itemname" name="itemname[]" class="form-control">
                                        <option disabled selected>اختر الصنف</option>
                                        <?php echo getValues($pdo); ?>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-2">السعر</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                  <input type="text" id="price" name="price[]" placeholder="-" readonly class="form-control price">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-2">الكمية</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                  <input class="form-control quantity" type="number" name="quantity[]" value="0" min="1">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
<input type="text" id= "total" placeholder="-" readonly class="form-control">
                    </div>
```

And PHP code:

```
<?php    
    require 'DBConnection.php';
    $code='';
    if(isset($_POST["code"])){
        $id = $_POST["code"];
        $get_c = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM all_menu WHERE `item_name` = '".$id."'");
        $get_c->execute(); 
        while ($row = $get_c->fetch()) {
            $code .= $row['price'];
        }
        echo $code.'.00';
    }
?>
```

And finally the JQuery code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var nextRowID = 0;
    $('#add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = ++nextRowID;
    $('#append').append('<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-lg-4"></label><div id ="diva" class="col-lg-4"><div class="box"><header><h5>تفاصيل الطلب</h5></header><div class="body getval"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-lg-2">الصنف</label><div class="col-lg-10"><select id="itemname'+id+'" name="itemname[]" class="form-control"><option disabled selected>اختر الصنف</option><?php echo getValues($pdo); ?></select></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-lg-2">السعر</label><div class="col-lg-10"><input type="text" id="price'+id+'" name="price[]" placeholder="-" readonly class="form-control price"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-lg-2">الكمية</label><div class="col-lg-10"><input class="form-control quantity" type="number" name="quantity[]" value="0" min="1"></div></div></div></div></div></div>');

      $('#itemname'+id+'').change(function(){
        var code = $(this).val();  
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'pages/GetPrice.php',
          data:{code:code},
          success: function(data){
            document.getElementById('price'+id+'').value = data;
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
          }
        });
      });
    });

  $('#itemname').change(function(){
        var code = $(this).val();  
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'pages/GetPrice.php',
          data:{code:code},
          success: function(data){
            document.getElementById('price').value = data;
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
          }
        });
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I do not see field for `Total` in your HTML

Comment: No no no, I have field for `Total` but I forgot to write here is it: `<input type="text" id= "total" placeholder="-" readonly class="form-control">`

Comment: OK, I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, then you need to set an event for whenever quantity is changed.  It will add all price*quantity and put the result in total.

```
function handleQuantityChange(){
  $('.quantity').unbind('change').change(function(){
    let dTot = 0.0;
    $('.price').each(function(){
      dTot += parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().next().find('.quantity').val())
    });
    $('#total').val(dTot)
  })
}
```

Here is a link to see my example: [jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/nfs8pjz5/)

Comment: Yesssssssss thanks a lot man I really appreciated. thanks so much ^^